# How to allow navigation for only certain linkIds in Here API (using custom routes or otherwise)?

Tags: navigation, here-api

I am trying to use Here Telematics Api to allow only certain road segments. First, we are doing route matching to get the linkIds and then generate allow and deny list of links (or road segments) which we want to navigate on. The number of links in deny list are more than 30,000.

Now, we want to use this in the navigation api of Here maps. To do this I saw 2 ways - 1) using avoidLinks query parameter and 2) using custom routes and overlays maps.

This is what I have tried so far.

**1. Using Navigation Api:**
I called the navigation api with `avoidLinks` query parameter. Here is how it will look:

```sh
curl https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXXX&app_code=XXXX&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&waypoint0=52.512623,13.321814&waypoint1=52.587389,13.279046&avoidLinks=linkId1,linkId2....
```

But because this is a get call, I cannot go beyond 20000 links, because otherwise I get status code 414, i.e. request uri is too long. So, this route is closed!

**2. Using Overlays and Navigation:**
Then I looked at [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/custom-routes.html) link, and tried using custom routes.
I used [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-routing-extension/topics/overlay-maps-layers.html) documentation to create overlay map using the overlays api:

```sh
curl https://cre.api.here.com/2/overlays/upload.json
```

But this again is a GET api, and it doesn't allow more than ~1000 linkIds as I again get http code 414 i.e. request uri is too long.

This overlays can be use

```sh
 curl http://cre.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json
  ?waypoint0=50.10951,8.68951
  &waypoint1=50.10703,8.68222
  &mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
  &overlays=overlaydemo1
  &storage=readonly
  &app_id=XXXX
  &app_code=XXXX
```

Now I am struck, because I cannot have 1 big overlay map, but I can create multiple maps, which is fine. But then in the navigation api, I can only use 1 overlay map.

Can you please help me in somehow solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Get api to upload overlay is used only for small request. For larger ones you have to use the post api. You can read more about it here : https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-routing-extension/topics/resource-overlay.html.

> For small examples, overlays can be submitted in a GET request, but
>   bigger overlays should be submitted via POST request, either as
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded or as multipart with one part named
>   overlay_spec.

Comment: Thank you. Will try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @here-developer-support, I tried following and get bad request with 'overlay_spec' is not present: 
curl -X POST -d '{"map_name": "overlaymapdemo1", "overlay_spec": [{"op": "restrict", "data": {"VEHICLE_TYPES": "custom1"}, "type": "access", "bidirectional": "true", "shape": [[52.53503, 13.32593], [52.53519, 13.3277]]}, {"op": "restrict", "data": {"VEHICLE_TYPES": "custom1"}, "type": "access", "bidirectional": "true", "shape": [[52.54644, 13.29427], [52.54714, 13.29695]]}]}' 'https://cre.api.here.com/2/overlays/upload.json?app_id=XXXX&app_code=XXXX'. Can you please help?